# Estimate progression rate of an number array

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics

Suppose I have an array of numbers [1,2,3,4,5] or [1,2,3,4,5...1000] both of these arrays have a progression rate of +1 regardless of the array size.

Is there a way of estimating a progression value for an array that doesn't contain consecutive numbers but yet are still progressive like [1,3,4,6,8,9].

I need this value because I want to compare two or more arrays and find out which one has a faster progression.

Thanks.

Comment: Were you imagining that the rate would be a fixed number regardless of size for any sequence? Or would you allow a function definition, similar to asymptotics? If it's fixed, then can't imagine there will be much more than the average difference between neighbouring elements across the array.

Comment: If your array is $A$ with elements $a_i$, then would you say your rate is something like $\frac{d a_i}{d i}$, although that isn't a very useful step? If you have an array where the elements are like $a_i = i^2$, then you would have a rate $~2i$.